# issue in testing with gruntjs and phantomjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, phantomjs

I want to create a Gruntfile.js to run bunch of phantomjs tests, when I execute > grunt run-test from commandline, it runs a bunch of tests. I created a Gruntfile.js and package.json which works ok and it reads bunch of tests from a directory. Now my problem is that when I write a phantomjs test and run the "grunt", it gives me this error:

> > Error: Cannot find module 'system'
> >     Error: Cannot find module 'phantom'

However phantomjs is installed before by using `npm install phantomjs`
Example of phantomtest which gives me the above error:

```
var system = require('system');
if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Try to pass some args when invoking this script!');
} else {
    system.args.forEach(function (arg, i) {
            console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
    });
}
phantom.exit();
```

When I run phantomjs test1 (name of the test file) it runs the test so I think maybe I should append "phantomjs" somewhere in the Gruntfile. Any idea?

Gruntfile.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'tests/*.js',
        '<%= nodeunit.tests %>',
      ],
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
      },
    },

    // Before generating any new files, remove any previously-created files.
    clean: {
      tests: ['tmp'],
    },

    // Configuration to be run (and then tested).
      testArgs: {
        configFile:"test/testConf.js",
        options: {
          args: {
            params: {
              number: 1,
              bool: true,
              str: "string",
              nil: null, // Null is not supported.
              obj: {
                array: [1, 2, 3],
                undef: undefined
              }
            },
            capabilities: {
              'browserName': 'chrome'
            },
            rootElement:"body",
            specs:["test/argsTest.js"],
            verbose:true
          }
        }
      },
      testDebug: {
        configFile:"test/testConf.js",
        options: {
          debug:true,
          args: {
            specs:["test/debugTest.js"],
          }
        }
      },

    // Unit tests.
    nodeunit: {
      tests: ['tests/*_test.js'],
    },

  });

  // Actually load this plugin's task(s).
  grunt.loadTasks('tests');

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-nodeunit');

  // Whenever the "test" task is run, first clean the "tmp" dir, then run this
  // plugin's task(s), then test the result.
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['clean']);

  // By default, lint and run all tests.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'test']);

};
```

Comment: What is in your testConf.js?

Comment: Good question! :) I use the above code from a plugin https://github.com/jfroom/portfolio-web/blob/master/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/test/testConf.js. So you think I should change this file?

Comment: I cannot seem to find any reference to the PhantomJS plugin you apparently are using. But probably there is some module not being loaded (correctly).

Comment: Well,I have installed phantomjs separately and  I thought if I write a Gruntfile that can read and run multiple file from a directory and put the phantom tests on this directory, the tests can be run. So I need to run phantom from this Gruntfile? can you take a look at https://github.com/darrennolan/codecept-phantomjs